# How can I insert data in a binary tree with Python?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I have a data set generated from

```
import numpy as np            
dataset = np.random.normal(50,10,100)
```

Record the min and max for this dataset.
Let [min, max] be the root node. Then it has 100 points. Let [min, min + d) and [max - d, max] (where d=(max-min)/2) be the left and right child respectively. Keep doing this.  Stop when the node has less than or equal to 5 points(which are in the dataset). How to find the number of points of each node?

I have constructed the original tree with node (1,2,3....From top to bottom and left to right), now I want to insert the data for each node. I also have written the function for splitting each interval. It just needs a recursive algorithm to complete. But how to make them together?

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.random.normal(50,10,100)
```

## For left child(function)

```
def split_L(l):
    d = (max(l)-min(l)) / 2
    print('max=', max(l))
    print('min=', min(l))
    print('d=', d)
    j = 0
    m = []

    for i in dataset:
        if i in l:
            j=j+1
    print('Number of points=',j)

    for k in l:
        if k < min(l)+d:
            m.append(k)

    while j > 5:
        return m
```

## For right child(function)

```
def split_R(l):
    d = (max(l)-min(l)) / 2
    print('max=', max(l))
    print('min=', min(l))
    print('d=', d)
    j = 0
    m = []

    for i in dataset:
        if i in l:
            j=j+1
    print('Number of points=',j)

    for k in l:
        if k >= max(l)-d:
            m.append(k)

    while j > 5:
        return m
```

## For tree

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [self.root_node()]

    def root_node(self):
        root_node = Node(1)
        return root_node


    def add_node(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        self.list.append(new_node)
        if len(self.list) % 2==0:
            self.list[len(self.list) // 2].left = new_node
        else:
            self.list[len(self.list) // 2].right = new_node

    def output_tree(self):
        for i in range(len(self.list)):
            print(self.list[i].data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = Tree()
    for i in range(2,100):
        tree.add_node(i)

    tree.output_tree()
```

Answer (score 0):

some tips.

1. you should have a manger class, because the dataset range decide the root node and the density of the points decide the depth. the tree may totally change when you add new point into dataset.
2. if you don't want to add new point into dataset, your "insert data" just means the construct stage, you don't have to resolve each level of the tree, your can just deal with the leaf nodes and define a property for their ancestor.
3. you don't have to construct the origin tree in this way, your can calculate the min length of every five adjacent points in a sorted dataset, then you can get the depth directly